# Looking for an apk parser

Tags: android, apk

Currently I am using net.dongliu.apk-parser but this is throwing exception for some of the apks which are signed with v2 only. The same issue also reported on their github but this is still open issue since 2018. It seems they are not working on the future release of the library.

Issue: https://github.com/hsiafan/apk-parser/issues/72
Maven :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.dongliu</groupId>
    <artifactId>apk-parser</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.10</version>
</dependency>
```

I am thinking of to replacing the apk parser, does anyone can suggest for the apk parser which is more active and also having a support of v1,v2,v3 apk parsing schemes.

I am using **java 8** with spring **2.0.5.RELEASE**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I used apktool, I don't know if it was the best idea.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).